# laravel api route not working after ssl

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, laravel-5

So i have recently installed SSL on my web application All routes are working fine but in case of APIs I am getting 404 error

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1.1.1.1
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

if i disable SSL, All is fine.But i want to redirect every request overs https and get the result same as http.

Comment: How were you able to fix this?

Comment: no luck in resolving